# highlighting all words of 1st String in 2nd String

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I am creating a variable highlightedSearchKey and then replacing searchKey string with highlightedSearchKey in name string

This works if the search String is continuous . But it doesn't highlight the discontinuos string.

eg: string1- good boy
    string2- This boy is good.    (Both good and boy should be highlighted)

searchKey (1st string) => This is the search string . I want to highlight the words of this string in 2nd one.

name (2nd string) => This is the result displayed .

```
    <c:set var="highlightedSearchKey" value="
   <label style='background-color:yellow'>
    ${searchKey}
   </label> "/>


   <td>${fn:replace(name, searchKey, highlightedSearchKey)}</td>
```

Comment: fn:replace will only do the replacement if the whole content of searchKey matches. "This boy is good" does not contain "good boy", so there's no match.

Comment: @aro_tech exactly, thats why I need an alternate to do this.

Comment: You may need to write a custom JSP tag that splits the search key into multiple search words and replaces text for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Please copy and paste this example.

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "fn" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<c:set var="string1"  value="good boy"/> 
<c:set var="string2"  value="This boy is good"/> 
<c:set var="array2"  value='${fn:split(string2, " ")}'/>
<html>
    <body>
        <c:forEach items="${array2}" var="current">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${fn:contains(string1, current)}">
                    <label style='background-color:yellow'>
                    ${current}
                    </label>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    ${current}
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>
        <br/>Another way<br/>
        <c:set var="string1"  value="goods boy"/> 
        <c:set var="array1"  value='${fn:split(string1, " ")}'/>
        <c:set var="string2"  value="This boy is good goodly aboy goods"/> 
        <c:set var="array2"  value='${fn:split(string2, " ")}'/>
        <c:forEach items="${array2}" var="current">
            <c:set var="found"  value="false"/>
            <c:forEach items="${array1}" var="curr">
                <c:if test="${curr == current}">
                    <c:set var="found"  value="true"/>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${found}">
                    <label style='background-color:yellow'>
                    ${current}
                    </label>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    ${current}
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>
    </body> 
</html>
```